# What does "kill" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, kill

What does this JavaScript do exactly?

```
parent.kill = 1;
```

This is used in a project I'm working on to do some sort of session expiration but I've never seen it before.  It's loaded in an `iframe` so I'm assuming that it is targeting the DOM `document.window`.

Comment: Could someone please edit/retag the OP? It's not so much a JavaScript Proper question as it is a DOM/webdev question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child iframe is setting the variable `kill` in the `parent` `window`'s global scope. What the `parent` does with that variable cannot be determined from just that line of javascript.

Comment: In other words, "kill" is not a standard property and so has no defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

to piggy-back off @crescentfresh's answer, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Reserved_Words) is a list of reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's part of the language - maybe part of a library?